# How can i use sass variables from json file?

Tags: json, sass, gulp

I need to use variables from `options.json` in `.sass` files and `.twig` templates with gulp. For twig all works great just with

```
pipe(data(function(file) {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('app/options.json'));
}))
.pipe(twig())
```

But with sass there is a problem, that I cannot solve.

I've found some similar questions, but for Ruby version. Also this gulp plugins doesn't fit because of link in json file:

- gulp-json-sass
- gulp-json-to-sass

My json file looks like this:

```
{
  "page": {
    "view": "mockup",
    "bg": "gradient",
    "buttons": "two"
  },
  "sass": {
    "bgOpacity": ".5",
    "bgPicture": "https://pics.freeartbackgrounds.com/midle/Street_in_Lund_Sweden_Background-1287.jpg",
    "bgColor": "$gradient-4"
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to use just part of json variables in sass file like this:

```
$opacity: $sass-bgOpacity;
```

Is this possible? Maybe there is another way, I just want to theme my entire site (`.twig` templates, `sass` variables) from one `options.json` file.

Very grateful for your help.

P.S. I'm not very good at English language so feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Amir, thank you for improving my question.

Comment: You're welcome. Checkout my answer. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks again and sorry for the long wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [node-sass-json-importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-json-importer)? It imports a json file into your sass, and you can access the variables with syntax like sass-variables. It hooks into [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)'s importer api.

Here is an example:

**style.scss**

```
@import 'some.json'

body {
    font-size: $font_size_in_json
}
```

**some.json**

```
{
    "font_size_in_json": "12px"
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.src('source/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sassImportJson({'isScss': true, 'cache': false}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/resources/css'))
```

Comment: If this post answers your question, please kindly accept it